# I have two primary keys how can I make it so that we can't use either one of the key again

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, create-table, unique-key

```
APPOINTMENT
<PK> PID:                  NUMBER(3,0)
<PK> appointmentDate:      TIMESTAMP
reason_for_visit:          VARCHAR(150)
assigned_Doctor:           REF DOCTOR_ty
```

I would like to make it so that a patient could only make one appointment and that the time of appointment cannot be conflicted. For example, if PID = 101 and appointmentDate is 03/17/20 3:00 PM. The following CANNOT happen PID = 102 03/17/20 3:00 PM or PID = 101 03/18/20 PM. I think I'm using primary keys the wrong way to represent this situation. Do you guys have suggestion to go on about implementing this issue? Do I have to create a separate table? Create a member function? because my appointment table is an object but I'm not experienced enough to write function just yet however if you do please help me implement this situation with function. -Thank you

Comment: *There can only be one Primary Key per table*. There can be multiple (possibly Candidate) Keys, represented as Unique Indices or a variety thereof. All Keys can be Compound Keys, depending on needs.

Comment: Why define PID as `NUMBER(3,0)`? That means you can have at most 1999 possible values (assuming negative and zero are allowed). That seems rather restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

A table can have only one primary key. But you can have as many unique keys as you want.

So you could make one coumn the primary key, and the other a unique key:

```
create table appointment(
    pid                 number(3, 0) primary key,
    appointment_date    timestamp unique,
    reason_for_visit    varchar2(150),
    ...
)
```

This set up prevents duplicates in both the `pid` and `appointment_date` columns.

Comment: What if more than 2 users have an appointment on the same date?  I think OP wants composite PK. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8932f

Answer (score 1):

You can define a unique constraint on the table for multiple columns.

```
ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENT
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (PID,appointmentDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

A table can have only one Primary Key, however a primary key can be build by several (up to 16) columns.

```
ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENT
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (PID, appointmentDate);
```